# why is glob.glob returning an empty list?

Tags: python, file, glob

Please i need help. I am using windows.
I am getting an empty list when I run this glob code. my ipynb file is inside the code folder, and I have 4 different folders inside the train and test folders that serve as labels for my image task.

```
# Setup train and testing paths
train_dir = "code/Datasets/train/**/*.jpg"
test_dir = "code/Datasets/test/**/*.jpg"

train_dir, test_dir

check = glob.glob(train_dir)
print(check)
```

I also tried pasting some images to enable me try this and it did not work

```
train_dir = "code/Datasets/train/*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possible issues:

1. When you use `**` in your `glob` path, you fail to pass `recursive=True`, so it won't actually treat `**` as special
2. Add `import os`, `print(os.getcwd())`. Is your working directory the one that contains `code/Datasets/...`? Relative paths like this require a specific working directory (separate from the *script* directory). If you were expecting it to use the script directory, you need to specify your path relative to `__file__`, e.g. `train_dir = os.path.join(__file__, "code/Datasets/train/**/*.jpg")`